# Why when i put a voltage through my photodiode its sensitivity doesn't change?

Tags: photodiode

I have a photodiode that I want to experiment; the problem is that when no voltage is applied to the circuit [image: circuit schema]

I get a voltage through the resistor of around 0.3V that change if I apply light. For any value that I put for the resistor I always get 0.3 volt.

The other thing is that for every voltage that I tried to put through into the circuit the measured voltage through the resistor is always the voltage that I put through the circuit plus the static voltage amount (the same 0.3 volt) so if I puts 5 volt through the circuit i will measure 5.3 volt through the resistor and it will do that for every value of resistor, so I'm not sure if it is normal since I don't really understand the need to put a voltage through the photodiode if the output current will always be the same

In conclusion :

1. When I don't put a voltage through the circuit the voltage measured through the resistor will always be the same for every value of the resistor; I will always get something near .3. I just remark that even if I don't put a resistor I will get this value so it make mes thinks i probably did  wiring error;
2. When I put a voltage through the circuit the value of the resistance will only change the initial voltage that I measure through the resistor but the maximum voltage will always be the voltage that I put through the circuit plus 0.3 V

Comment: You don't need to bias the photodiode with a voltage. Think of it as a little solar cell. Works just fine without a bias voltage. However, you can reverse bias the photodiode with a voltage which increases the width of the depletion region which is a bit like moving the plates farther apart on a capacitor which reduces the capacitance of the photodiode which makes it respond faster. It's possible the dark current and leakage current is entirely swamping out your photo current because your photodiode is too small and your light source too weak.

Comment: If you're going to experiment with using just a resistor, I recommend you get a really, really big area photodiode. 5-7mm^2 if you can. You can get them for like $1 in plastic packages like the BPW34/BPW34S/VBPW34S. Also, please provide more details about your circuit such as the datasheet for the photodiode and the resistance values you tried.

Comment: the photodiode that i use is a BPW34 and the value or resistor that i tried was a 120K 1M 2M 3M also i tried to use voltage from 0-10 V

Comment: Another thing to consider is that your Multimeter probably has an input impedance of only 10MOhms. Which means that it will have trouble accurately measuring across resistors larger than 1MOhm. What readings do you get if you have no bias voltage and take it outside on a bright sunny day versus covering it up with your hands (most plastics are transparent to near-IR so note that if you are using a material to cover it).

Comment: If all the reverse bias you apply ends up across the resistor, then you're giving the diode too much light and saturating the circuit.  For VIS/NIR light, you'll get close to 1 amp per watt of optical power, so with a 1M resistor, you get ~ 1 million volts per watt.  That means you're limited to measuring nanowatt powers unless you use a smaller resistor.